# JQuery Mobile format variable output into list

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am trying to format the output from variable containing an array as a Jquery mobile list. However I am just getting a normal bullet list. If I copy the [example Jquery mobile list](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/listview/#&ui-state=dialog) code into a variable and output this to html, I get a list however no styling from the Jquery mobile. 
It appears the variable output cannot see the styling information from Jquery mobile? The rest of the page displays correctly.

This code is within a function on the same page as my links to the CSS / JS files, and loads on click.

```
 var output = '<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">';
 for(name in results){
 output += '<li>'+results[name]+'</li>';
 }
 output += '</ul>';


 $("#TomTop").html(output);
```

Comment: `$("[data-role=listview]").listview();` after `$("#TomTop").html(output);`.

Comment: @Omar Thanks, how come the data-role needs to be stated twice? Also i now get a space between the styling of each list item, i.e The first item is styles correctly and the second one, however instead of touching each other there is a 10px approx gab between the list items?

Comment: what do you mean by `data-role` stated twice? if `#TomTop` is the id of the listview, then `var output = '<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="TomTop>'; and `$("#TomTop").html(output).listview();` will refresh listview. Regarding the padding, please post more details of your markup or create a fiddle.

Comment: check this, go through code thoroughly http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/9pgMq/

Comment: @Omar It was a trailing <pre> tag that I had accidentally copied in. If you put your solution into a question I will accept it.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the fiddle you've provided, you have to do the following changes.

- Refrain from using `.ready()` in jQuery Mobile, instead, bind events on `pagecreate`.

  ```
  $(document).on("pagecreate", "#Page_ID", function () {
    $(".selector").on("click", function () { });
  });
  ```
- Dynamically added elements enhancement:

  When adding items dynamically to a *div* you can enhance all elements within it at once, using `.enhanceWithin()`. However, if you want to do modifications to a widget i.e. *listview*, you need to use widget's function `.listview()`.

  ```
  $("#TomTop").html(output).enhanceWithin();
  ```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/9pgMq/)**